# How to create a new column takes the value from the sum of another column each row?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, partition-by

Like taking the value from the first row 60, then add it to the new value from the next row and so on, like the example of the below table.

```
     field       A                             B
0      u       60.0                           60.0
1      v       78.0   >>     60.0  + 78.0  =  138.0
2      w       42.0   >>     138.0 + 42.0  =  180.0
3      x       61.0   >>     180.0 + 61.0  =  241.0
4      y       36.0   >>     241.0 + 36.0  =  277.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has a built-in "cumulative sum"

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "field": ["u", "v", "w", "x", "y"],
        "A": [60, 78, 42, 61, 36],
    }
)

df["B"] = df["A"].cumsum()

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  field   A    B
0     u  60   60
1     v  78  138
2     w  42  180
3     x  61  241
4     y  36  277
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you are using a Pandas dataframe and it is named `df` you can do that operation in this way (**without using builtin pandas .cumsum package**):

```py
columns_A = df["A"] #obtain the element of the columns A as a series
new_col= []
for i in range(len(columns_A)):
    if i <=0: # the first element tha can't be sum up
        new_col.append(a[i])
    else: # after the first element we start with cumulative sum
        new_col.append(new_col[i-1]+a[i]) #here with new_row[i-1] we obtain the previous element respect the 
        #the current one and thanks to that we can obtain the cumulative sum
df["B"] = new_col #here we assign the name of the column and add the values to the dataframe
```